# Autocomplete com typeahead e JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, autocompletar, typeahead

Tenho um projeto em ASP.NET MVC e nele um script para autocomplete utilizando typeahead com prefetch:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // Sonstructs the suggestion engine
            var ativos = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                // The url points to a json file that contains an array of country names
                prefetch: 'ativos.json'
            });

            // Initializing the typeahead with remote dataset
            $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'ativos',
                source: ativos,
                limit: 7 /* Specify maximum number of suggestions to be displayed */
            });
        });
```

E o arquivo JSON na mesma pasta, da forma: `["petr4","usim5","itub4"]`o erro que estou recebendo no console :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Não estou entendendo o por quê do script não conseguir obter o arquivo JSON. Creio que devo ter que realizar alguma chamada via AJAX que me retorne esse JSON mas não sei como ficaria. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque a URL começando do root (endereço para webroot) do seu servidor. Use essa sintaxe também dentro do objeto que você passa para o construtor do Bloodhound:

```
prefetch: {url : 'path/to/ativos.json'}
```

Comment: AEEE CARA, funcionou *-*, mas tive que colocar o arquivo JSON na raiz do projeto!!